# How to add payment per project in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have two projects on Heroku- one personal and one work related. I am using my corporate card and want to avoid  paying for my personal project. But in Settings I can't figure out a way to add a credit card per project. How can I separate projects by payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify payment details per project, but what you can do is to create a "Team" and move the work related project there. Teams allow you to specify payment information separately.